# Map Control-Shift-Tab in rxvt-unicode

Tags: key-mapping, urxvt

I'd like to map the keybinding
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in `rxvt-unicode`.
I managed to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> as follows. The
corresponding entry in `.Xresources` is

```
URxvt.keysym.Control-Tab: \033[27;5;9~
```

Using `cat -v` confirms that this mapping works:

```
$ cat -v
^[[27;5;9~
```

The sequence `^[[27;5;9~` can then be used in applications like
`vim` for mapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. I would
expect the following `.Xresources` entry to work the same.

```
URxvt.keysym.Control-Shift-Tab: \033[27;6;9~
```

However, `cat` does not show the correct mapping:

```
$ cat -v
^[[Z
```

How to set up the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> mapping?

**Edit**

The mappings

```
URxvt.keysym.Control-ISO_Left_Tab: \033[27;6;9~    
URxvt.keysym.Control-Shift-ISO_Left_Tab: \033[27;6;9~
```

behave the same. After first pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, releasing both and then pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> *twice* and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, releasing all and then pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> *twice* I get the following output:

```
$ cat -v
^[[27;5;9~
^[[27;5;9~


^[[27;6;9~↵
^[[27;6;9~M-bM-^FM-5
```

- Case <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>: The first return makes the input appear again as output.
- Case <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>: The first return produces the sign `↵`, the second return produces the last line shown above.

**Next edit: More information**

> What happens if you press ctrl-shift (release both without pressing any
>   keys), then enter, in a different window?

In a different urxvt window? When I press Ctrl+Shift and release both keys a
strident yellow box appears in the lower left corner: `KEYCAP PICTURE INSERT
MODE` it seems to come from urxvt, it does not appear in other applications.

> Or even just ctrl-shift-tab then enter in a different window (i mean not
>   rxvt, like in a gedit window or the web browser or something.)

I get a new line.

> What happens if you press shift+ctrl+tab [i.e. shift down, ctrl down, tab,
>   ctrl up, shift up] instead, or vice versa if that was what you were doing?

In urxvt?

```
$ cat -v
shift+ctrl+tab then enter: ^[[27;6;9~
ctrl+shift+down: ↓
ctrl+shift+up: ↑
shift+down: ^[[b
shift+up: ^[[a
ctrl+down: ^[Ob
ctrl+up: ^[Oa
tab: |       | (tab)
```

> I'm trying to narrow down things because I think you might have some sort of
>   mapping on "ctrl+shift" in xcompose or something.

Not that I'm aware of, but you never know.

> What is the output of xev when you press "ctrl+shift+tab, enter"?

```
KeyPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0xb4, subw 0x0, time 311734869, (567,395), root:(567,411),
    state 0x0, keycode 66 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0xb4, subw 0x0, time 311734971, (567,395), root:(567,411),
    state 0x4, keycode 62 (keysym 0xffe2, Shift_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0xb4, subw 0x0, time 311736110, (567,395), root:(567,411),
    state 0x5, keycode 23 (keysym 0xfe20, ISO_Left_Tab), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0xb4, subw 0x0, time 311736494, (567,395), root:(567,411),
    state 0x5, keycode 23 (keysym 0xfe20, ISO_Left_Tab), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0xb4, subw 0x0, time 311736525, (567,395), root:(567,411),
    state 0x5, keycode 62 (keysym 0xffe2, Shift_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0xb4, subw 0x0, time 311736525, (567,395), root:(567,411),
    state 0x4, keycode 66 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0xb4, subw 0x0, time 311737530, (567,395), root:(567,411),
    state 0x0, keycode 36 (keysym 0xff0d, Return), same_screen YES,
"   XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d) "
"   XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d) "
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 35, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0xb4, subw 0x0, time 311737633, (567,395), root:(567,411),
    state 0x0, keycode 36 (keysym 0xff0d, Return), same_screen YES,
"   XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d) "
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: I have no idea if this will work, so not posting as an answer yet, but try Control-Shift-ISO_Left_Tab or Control-ISO_Left_Tab.

Comment: @Random832 It is definitely a nudge in the in the right direction, but the mapping behaves weird. When I press `Ctrl-Tab` `cat -v` outputs the mentioned sequence, `Ctrl-Shift-Tab` outputs the correct sequence `^[[27;6;9~` however the next key press is not interpreted like usual. In the `cat -v` output `Ctrl-Shift-Tab`+ enter displays as `^[[27;6;9~↵`, instead of two lines `^[[27;6;9~` (one for input, one for the output). This mapping would not work in vim. Do you have another idea?

Comment: Like a literal ↵ symbol? Are you releasing ctrl-shift before you hit enter? Which of the two mappings I suggested worked, so I can start writing an answer?

Comment: @Random832 I added more detailled information (see edit). Thanks for your effort so far.

Comment: What happens if you press ctrl-shift (release both without pressing any keys), then enter, in a different window? Or even just ctrl-shift-tab then enter in a different window (i mean not rxvt, like in a gedit window or the web browser or something.) What happens if you press shift+ctrl+tab [i.e. shift down, ctrl down, tab, ctrl up, shift up] instead, or vice versa if that was what you were doing? I'm trying to narrow down things because I think you might have some sort of mapping on "ctrl+shift" in xcompose or something. What is the output of `xev` when you press "ctrl+shift+tab, enter"?

Comment: @Random832 I added the information to my question.

Comment: not "ctrl+up". I meant "press shift, press ctrl, press tab, release tab, release ctrl, release shift" - i.e. the specific order of pressing keys ("down") and releasing them ("up"), i.e. to hit shift before ctrl instead of ctrl before shift. -- EDIT: I've edited the answer with a link to something about the 'keycap insert mode' - it looks like this is your other issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is often mapped to the <kbd>ISO_Left_Tab</kbd> keysym in X11, so some programs may need this instead of a literal 'shift-tab' in their configuration.

urxvt has a strange mapping on ctrl+shift, it looks like you will have to recompile to disable it: see [this page](http://wilmer.gaa.st/blog/archives/36-rxvt-unicode-and-ISO-14755-mode.html) for more details. EDIT It looks like in recent versions of rxvt you can simply add

```
URxvt.iso14755_52: False
```

Answer (score 5):

I've got `S-Tab` working with this :

```
URxvt.keysym.C-Tab: \033{
URxvt.keysym.Control-Shift-ISO_Left_Tab: \033} 
! disable ctrl-shift
URxvt*iso14755: False 
URxvt*iso14755_52: False
```

and in vim I have

```
nmap ^[{ :tabnext<cr>
imap ^[{ <ESC>:tabnext<cr>
nmap ^[} :tabprevious<cr>
imap ^[} <ESC>:tabprevious<cr>
```

Comment: ISO_Left_Tab <-- that's what exactly worked for me! Not other answers in this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:  You can disable the Control-Shift ISO 14755 mode - at least in modern URxvt - by adding the following to your .Xdefaults file (or maybe .Xresources, depending on your system):

```
URxvt.iso14755:    false
URxvt.iso14755_52: false
```